# Go back without pressing mobile back button

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

there are two fragments. first is main fragment and second is editprofile fragment. if we click on editprofile button then it navigate to editpeofile fragment. if we click save changes button then it will navigate to main fragment.

main fragment is fetching data again from server.
I need a method to go back without pressing mobile's back button.

Comment: You want to go back to where?

Comment: main fragment.... I just want that action, which will happen when we press back button.

Comment: I want to make a button on screen , which will act same as mobile's back button

Answer (score 0):

link : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal#java

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: it is not working same as pressing back button of mobile

Comment: fragmentTransaction.remove(yourfragment).commit() try this

Comment: I am not using fragment manager. I am using navigation architecture of google jetpack.

Comment: when working with activities we have onBackPressed(). I need same method like this one, but in fragment